How to write List<Object> in avro?
I have some problem. I need to create avro schema for Kafka. In one of my java class i have field with list of Object:
public class Model {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> some;                   
}

How can I write something like that in avro schema?

I try something like that but i have some errors:
{
                                                                                                                                "name": "model",
                                                                                                                                "type": [
                                                                                                                                    "null",
                                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                                        "type": "record",
                                                                                                                                        "name": "Model",
                                                                                                                                        "fields": [
                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                "name": "some",
                                                                                                                                                "type": [
                                                                                                                                                    "null",
                                                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                                                        "type": "array",
                                                                                                                                                        "items": "string"
                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                ]
                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                        ]
                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                ]
                                                                                                                            }

